# Ugly C# WPF code required to activate storyboards

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

To activate Storyboards which I declare via XAML, I'm finding that I'm writing the following ugly code sequence rather a lot;

```
(SomeElement.TryFindResource("SomeStoryboard") as Storyboard)?.Begin();
```

What I'd really like is to just write;

```
SomeStoryboard.Begin();
```

Is there some way I could declare/address a Storyboard more directly?  This would aid code readability and also allow compile-time rather than runtime resolution of the object from C#

Answer (score 4):

For simple scenarios, you should use `Trigger`/`DataTrigger` instead of managing storyboards directly. Here is an example:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAnimationEnabled}" Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="MyStoryBoard" Storyboard="{StaticResource MyStoryBoardResourceKey}"/>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="MyStoryBoard"/>
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

`IsAnimationEnabled` is some `Boolean` property on your viemodel (or view), which you can set from code to enable or disable the animation.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `EventTriggers` like so:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.300" Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize" To="28" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.800" Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize" To="18" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you, but if you are sure that that resource is there you can have a private variable on your window and initialize it in the constructor like:

```
    private Storyboard SomeStoryboard;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Storyboard = SomeElement.TryFindResource("SomeStoryboard") as Storyboard;           
    }
```

And then just use it. You will have to check for nulls.

Or you can write a readonly property-wrapper:

```
    private Storyboard SomeStoryboard
    {
        get
        {
            var someStoryboard = SomeElement.TryFindResource("SomeStoryboard") as Storyboard;
            if (someStoryboard == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("SomeStoryboard is not found");
                //or
                someStoryboard = new Storyboard();
            } 
            return someStoryboard;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This question was originally raised because I have been trying to find a way to avoid using TryFindResource() completely.   Your suggestion of 'cacheing' the lookup in to a private member is fine for repeated use of referenced items, but doesn't address the ugly runtime resolution which is what I was trying to achieve really.

Comment: @Puffin Yes, and it wont help with compile-time checks, but I dont think that there is any way to access resources like components. So this approach at least will move all that ugly code to only 1 place.